# Showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})$ is not Galois.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

> Why $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})$ is not Galois?

I have only this:  Let   $\alpha=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}.$

If $\alpha=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}$ then $(\alpha^2-3)^2=3$, then $f(x)=x^4-6x^2+6$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (Eisenstein with the prime 2).

Therefore $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=4$

Now, to check that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]\neq |\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb Q(\alpha))|$, is there a standard procedure to prove that the extension is not Galois?

Actualization 1.
I got the following: If $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3}}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ then $\sqrt{6}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. As also $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ we have that $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha).$
Because $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ has the same degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Now, $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$. I have this:

\begin{eqnarray} 3&=&a^2+2b^2+3c^2+6d^2\\
0&=&ab+3cd\\
1&=&6ac+4bd\\
0&=&ad+bc
\end{eqnarray}
and here I am still stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The roots of the minimal polynomial of $\;\sqrt{3+\sqrt3}\;$ are

$$\pm\sqrt{\frac{6\pm2\sqrt3}2}=\pm\sqrt{3\pm\sqrt3}$$

The question is thus: is $\;\sqrt{3-\sqrt3}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3+\sqrt3})\;$ ? Because if it is then the signs in front of the square root don't make much difference: all the roots of the minimal polynomial would then be contained in the extension and thus this would be Galois...Try this way.

Comment: it's laborious to show that $\sqrt{3-\sqrt 3}$ belong or not to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3+\sqrt 3})$...

Comment: I got the following:
If $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3}}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ then $\sqrt{6}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. As also $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ we have that $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) \subset\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$...

Comment: @eraldcoil That's a good start. You probably know that both $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3,\sqrt2)$ are degree 4 extensions. If one is contained in the other, then ____. Is it possible that $\alpha\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3,\sqrt2)$?

Comment: If one is contained in the other, then are isomorphic?

Comment: @Surb Yes, it is. Yet Jykri already gave a good idea to try.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen Now I understand your clue.
As vector spaces, if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) $and has the same degree then (vector space) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha).$
Therefore $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ i.e. $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$...